# Active state sticks with block elements in anchor tags

Tags: html, css

I have markup that looks like this:

```
<dl class="synthModels">
    <a href="#" class="soundTest">
        <dt><span>Bass Drum</span></dt>
        <dd>Bass drum description.</dd>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="soundTest">
        <dt><span>Bass Drum</span></dt>
        <dd>Bass drum description.</dd>
    </a>
</dl>
```

And CSS like this:

```
.synthModels a:hover dt {
    color: #ff571b;
}
.synthModels a:active dt {
    color: #aed9e0;
}
```

The hover works fine, but for some reason the active state remains active even after you have clicked the link, rather than only while the link is being clicked. You can try it out for yourself here, where it says "Bass Drum", "Synth Clap", etc.:

http://sans-concept.com/as/drumspillage.html

Any ideas why this is happening? I tried removing the DL and swapping the DT/DD with H3/P, but the issue remained. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out. I tried changing my anchor tag to display:block and that absolutely fixed the issue. Hooray!

Answer (score 0):

The active selector doesn't work with in page jump anchors, only with external anchors.
With in page jump anchors, active selector will apply style to all in page anchors.
It will work with external links, for example when you have a webpage with a menu apering on every page, active selector can be used to evidentiate in the menu the page you are currently on.

In your case, you can try to use focus selector instead.

Comment: Thanks Gimmy, I'm not sure I'm following you though. I tried changing the href to a url rather than an in-page hash (#) but the problem still remains. Changing the selector from active to focus removes the problem but now does not affect the link at all when clicked.